# Disable popup messages in CMD start command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I want to create a Windows BAT or VBS that tries to start a program silently. If the program does not exist, I would like it to terminate silently, without showing any alert window.

I am trying the following bat named `startSilently.bat`:

```
@echo off
start %1
```

When I type `startSilently.bat chrome` in CMD, Google Chrome opens as it should.

But when I type `startSilently.bat nonexistent`, then I get a popup message telling me:

> Windows cannot find 'nonExistent'. Make sure you typed the name
>   correctly, and then try again.

[image]

**I wish this message did not show up. Is there a way to do this?**

Note: I cannot use `call` instead of `start` because I don't know where the program is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in a .vbs this way:

```
On Error Resume Next
WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell").run WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0)
```

You then call it like that:

```
cscript scriptname.vbs appname
```

If in your *start silently* desire you prefer that the application start minimized, you can add the **intWindowStyle** argument with value = 7 like that:

```
On Error Resume Next
WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell").run WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0),7
```

... but that may not work with all applications. For example, notepad will start minimized but not chrome.

Comment: Is it possible to the script to return 1 when the program does not exist? It is always returning 0.

Comment: Add this at the end:
 If Err.Number<>0 Then WScript.Quit 1